# How does one go about getting permissions for installing zipped files from a cd.

Tags: permissions

I am trying to unzip zipped files on a cd to install in a program on my computer.  It keeps telling me I don't have permissions.  I try to reset the permissions but it only gets worse.  I tell it to make it create and remove files and it changes it to none.  How quirky is that?  Help, Help, Help!!!!!!

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 0):

Its look like your zip has no read permission.
can you give read permission and try to unzip

```
chmod a+r myfiles.zip
```